# Can’t remember the name of the writing style

Tags: creative-writing

So I am interested in picking up writing and one of the styles I was interested in some 10 years ago I can’t remeber the name or much of the rules.

But it writes about 1 place or thing but at 2 different times.

For example, A pool when it’s not used it’s silent and airy, still and clear. 
But when it’s used if loud and vibrate, splashed and ripples.

This is in no way shape or form the style. It’s more full sentences like “the surface of the water is like glass”

I know this isn’t much to go on but any help would be great!!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Lapis, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. I'm having difficult understanding exactly what you are looking for here. Your description of the style and your example don't seem to entirely line up. Perhaps if you give a longer example of the style, or an extract of somewhere you read it? Then we can identify that style. Good luck and happy writing!